Xrandr new mode resolution getting out of display (black spaces)
So I Have two monitors
the primary one is on Integrated Graphics intel
and 2nd monitor is on Nvidia GPU GT 630 (of which I can't download the driver due to kernel 6.10.11 not supporting old drivers ) I use Nouveau drivers for my 2nd monitor which by default supports 1024x768 resolution which I have been using for months now but now
I Used "xrandr" new mode of 1366x768 )my second monitor supported resolution
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --newmode "1366x768_60.00" 85.25 1366 1440 1576 1784 768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1-1 "1366x768_60.00"
xrandr --output DVI-I-1-1 --mode "1366x768_60.00"
xrandr --output DVI-I-1-1 --mode "1366x768_60.00" --left-of DP-2

I used these bash commands script on startup but it cuts off my display out of the screen a little bit black screen at the bottom of the monitor cutting the display off the top.
I don't know how to solve this display cutoff issue which
(Monitor side buttons don't work)
my 2nd monitor (BENQ GL940)
OS dist: Debian Lorikeet Parrot OS 6.2|
This is the Xrandr added resolution in the end 1366x768
DVI-I-1-1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
1024x768      60.04    60.00
960x720       60.00
928x696       60.05
896x672       60.01
1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82
960x600       59.93    60.00
960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82
800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
840x525       60.01    59.88
864x486       59.92    59.57
848x480       60.00
700x525       59.98
800x450       59.95    59.82
640x512       60.02
700x450       59.96    59.88
640x480       60.00    59.94
720x405       59.51    58.99
684x384       59.88    59.85
640x400       59.88    59.98
640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
512x384       60.00
512x288       60.00    59.92
480x270       59.63    59.82
400x300       60.32    56.34
432x243       59.92    59.57
320x240       60.05
360x202       59.51    59.13
320x180       59.84    59.32
1366x768_60.00  59.88*

Welcome to AskUbuntu! However, questions about Debian are off topic here but they are on topic at https://unix.stackexchange.com Just use your existing stackexchange credentials to add that site to your profile and you can ask the question there. You may find that this question already has an answer. For example if I read correctly, you want to use the same resolution on both monitors and this answer here may be a solution although you would probably have to modify the command slightly.

There are other answers that deal with screen offset and this is possible with xrandr commands. I've done this manually with xrandr but it's been many years and I haven't done much of a search today so I don't have links to those answers right now. You could add --auto --panning as mentioned in the comments to the referenced answer although I've never had much luck with this. Additionally, they mention making it a "mirror" of the other screen but it looks like they're just using the same resolution, not actually making it a mirror which would display the same content on both screens as well.

Okay, I think I found an answer that has the offset options included in the xrandr command.

And this related answer goes into more detail.

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.
